# React how to create custom overflow ellipsis

Tags: reactjs

I would like to create a top navigation with a variable amount of items. All items that don't fit into the bar should not be rendered. There will be a little "..." icon that shows a sub-menu when you hover over it, that display the remaining nav items. Any ideas on how to achieve this? I can't seem to render the nav items conditional to the parents width.

I tried setting a ref on my navigation bar and check the scroll width against the client width but it didn't work. Even if I got it to work, I would still render one item more than I should because I don't know the width of the children beforehand.

```
                <div ref={ref} className="nav-list">
                    {ref ? items.map(i => {
                        return ref.scrollWidth <= ref.clientWidth ? (
                            <div className="nav-item" key={i.id}>
                              {i.title}
                            </div>
                        ) : false;
                    }) : false}
                    <div className="nav-remaining">
                        <div>
                            //render remaining items
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I saw someone implementing this by adding the children recursively and then backtrack to remove all children that are overflowing. But I have now idea on how to implement this approach in react.

Comment: [How TO - Hoverable Dropdown](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp)

Comment: Thank you for you help, but the problem is not the dropdown, but how to determine which items need to be rendered into the navigation bar and which items need to be inserted into the dropdown. For that I would need to know the width of the top bar and the width of every item.